# Dynamically set "Readonly" in ColdFusion cfinput

Tags: coldfusion

Is it possible to use an `cfif` statement to add "Readonly" to my ?

My URL (example):

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/page_review.cfm?action=view&rfqID=2
```

For example:

```
<cfset pageAction="URL.action">
<cfset rfqID="URL.rfqID">
<label>*Sales Engineer:</label> 
<cfinput type="text" name="sales_engineer" 
value="" class="rfq_text_input" 
<cfif pageAction eq "view"> readonly</cfif>/>
```

My theory why it is not working is because I am running the if statement inside of the input. But I am not sure how to test for this.

Comment: Don't use `cfinput` (or any other ColdFusion UI functionality) as they are poorly implemented, out of date and limited in functionality. You can use your logic if you simply change the tag to `<input>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't nest tags like this:

```
<cfinput etc <cfif>whatever</cfif> >
```

You can do that with a simple input tag.  Otherwise, you have to do this sort of thing.

```
<cfif whatever>
<cfinput something>
<cfelse>
<cfinput something else>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks Dan I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that but I guess if that is the only way.

Comment: You wouldn't have to do that if you used standard HTML and not `<cfinput>`. There is nothing in your example that needs to use `<cfinput>`, try using just `<input>`

Comment: I suggest taking a closer look at @Twillen's answer.  The ternary operator more closely resembles what you were attempting.  I had never thought of trying it.  I just did with a simpler example, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using the `cfinput`, the tag has an attribute for readonly. Conditionally set the attributes text to a value other then an empty string when you want to prevent the user form typing into the field.

```
<cfform>
  <cfoutput>
     <!--- Readonly attribute of cfinput (Read only) --->
     <cfinput type="text" name="text" readOnly="#(true)?"ReadOnly":""#" value="read only">
     <!--- Readonly attribute of cfinput (editable)  --->
     <cfinput type="text" name="text2" readOnly="#(false)?"ReadOnly":""#" value="editable">
     <!--- HTML input --->
     <input type="text" name="text3" #(true)?"ReadOnly":""# value="read only" />
  </cfoutput>
</cfform>
```

Comment: I just tested this, and I see this as being the better answer.